# Overload the output operator << to work with STL list iterator

Tags: c++, linked-list, overloading, operator-keyword

I have a Point2D class

**Point2D**

```
class Point2D
{
 public:

           int getX() const;
           int getY() const;

           void setX(int);
           void setY(int);

 protected:

             int x;
             int y;

};
```

I am trying to overload the output operator << to work with Point2D iterator  **p2d_list.begin()** but i am unsure how to do it , this is my attempt

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& afile, Point2D* p2)
{

               afile<<left
                    <<setw(1)
                    <<"["
                    <<left
                    <<setw(5)
                    <<p2->getX()
                    <<" ,"
                    <<left
                    <<setw(5)
                    <<p2->getY()
                    <<" ]    "
                    <<left
                    <<setw(6)
                    <<p2->getScalarValue()
                    <<endl;

                return afile;


}
```

In my main function

```
int main()
{

   list<Point2D> p2d_list;

   list<Point2D>::iterator p2 = p2d_list.begin();

        while ( p2 != p2d_list.end() )
        {
            cout<<p2; //error here
            p2++;

        }

}
```

I am getting the following Error

**error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)**

How do i overload the output operator << so that it works with Point2D iterator  **p2d_list.begin()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to output `iterator`, not `Point2D`. You should dereference iterator first.
In your case it should be

```
cout << &(*p2);
```

, but I have no idea, why your `operator <<` receives pointer, instead of ref/const-ref. It should be

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& afile, const Point2D& p2)
```

and then output should be

```
cout << *p2;
```

Comment: what changes must i make to the overload function?? and how should i cout ??

Comment: @Computernerd use `.`, instead of `->` when address to fields of object. It's all.

Comment: it doesnt work i am getting the same error: Error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'Point2D' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: Show code. Is your `operator <<` declaration changed as I advice?

Answer (score 0):

You need to overload the operator for `list<Point2D>::iterator` type instead of `Point2D*`

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& afile, list<Point2D>::iterator &p2)
{

           afile<<left
                <<setw(1)
                <<"["
                <<left
                <<setw(5)
                <<(*p2)->getX()
                <<" ,"
                <<left
                <<setw(5)
                <<(*p2)->getY()
                <<" ]    "
                <<left
                <<setw(6)
                <<(*p2)->getScalarValue()
                <<endl;

            return afile;


}
```